# Eclipse build path with other projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, dependencies, project

I've got several projects in Eclipse (all are Maven projects) and one main project (also Maven project) which depends on the rest. I tried add this dependency by setting java build path (right click on project -> preferences -> java build path -> (tab) projects -> add). But there is a problem while executing maven install goal - this is compilation error: ... (class) ... "cannot be resolved" ... - this is definitely looks like maven does't see my resources from other projects. Eclipse is only warning me something like this: "Classpath entry /my-subproject1 will not be exported or published. Runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions may result." These warnings referenced to each subproject and occurs in main project. There is no error messages from Eclipse. In my main project, where I'm importing classes from subprojects, I can right-click on one of the import and choose "Open declaration" and there is valid reference to class from one of my subproject - so it looks like Eclipse sees my dependencies (there is no eclipse errors while building workspace - only these warnings mentioned above) from other projects, but maven doesn't see them while compilation.

Have you got any ideas how can I fix this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare your dependencies in the pom.xml for Maven. Maven doesn't recognize any Eclipse specific configurations (like Build Path etc.): [Maven Tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html)

If you use the [m2eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), it will configure your Eclipse build path according to your pom.xml configuration

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've got these dependencies in my main project pom, but there is still the same problem :(

Comment: Is your main project pom a multimodule build or just a regular maven project? If the latter, then you must have installed all projects for itself at least one time, so that they show up in your local maven repository.

Comment: All projects are regular maven project. I will try your advice. Thanks

Comment: I would also advise you to read the docs about the multimodule build. It seems reasonable for your project structure. With a multimodule build, all modules (i.e. all your projects) are built when you build your main project. So you don't have to care to build every single project, if there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this maven problem?

Maven needs jar file made from other project inside maven repository.

I don't know much about maven eclipse plugin but so far, in my observation, it seems like it works this way.

So that this case need to build other project so that create it's jar file.

But this takes so much time.

Comment: I think, that when you've got maven project, which depends on other maven project, which you have imported in your workspace - m2e plugin will take care of it. You won't have to build dependency-jar every time you change something in your code. This works on my multi-module web app configuration (if I change something in my module - I don't have to rebuild this jar when I run main web project on Tomcat; eclipse does this automatically). When I go to properties of my main web project - I can see, that modules are references to projects (not jars on local m2 repo).